# Installed Pytorch 1.12 in the environment but detects version 1.10.0+cpu

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda3

Recently, I have installed pytorch 1.12.1 in the conda environment. After installation, I checked the version of pytorch using `print(torch.__version__)`, it returns `1.10.0+cpu`. I also checked the available packages in the environment. It shows pytorch version `1.12.1` as shown in figure below.[image]
I am unable to understand why it is detecting version `1.10.0+cpu`. I even reinstalled Anaconda python in Windows, still it shows same version `1.10.0+cpu` even in the `base` environment.[image]
Can someone please figure it out.

Comment: Do you have CUDA drivers installed and working? Also the `cudatoolkit` Python package?

Comment: Yes, I checked it using nvcc -V, it shows 11.7. Also, nvidia-smi works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried uninstalling the existing pytorch version `1.10.0+cpu` using pip/conda but nothing was working. I was finally able to get rid of it by deleting the old Python folder at 'C:\Users\Vikrant\AppData\Roaming\Python'. I created a new environment and installed Pytorch 1.12.1. Now, everything is working fine. Thanks!